# Ormlite - Access Two Databases from the same activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite, ormlite

I have an Android app where I need to access two different databases from the same activity.

I am using Ormlite to read from/write to database.

```
    public class MyActivity extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<MyDatabaseHelper>
```

I need to use another database helper for the other database.

Can anyone direct me on how to achieve this?

Should I use the same DatabaseHelper and make modifications there to support both databases? Or is there a way to use different databaseHelpers in the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think that the better solution is to use separate helpers and not to extend `OrmLiteBaseActivity`.

```
public class DatabaseHelperA extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    public static DatabaseHelper getInst(){
        return inst;
    }

    public static void init(Context c){
        if (inst == null) inst = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(c, DatabaseHelperA.class);
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "a.db", null, 1);
    }
}

public class DatabaseHelperB extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    public static DatabaseHelper getInst(){
        return inst;
    }

    public static void init(Context c){
        if (inst == null) inst = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(c, DatabaseHelperB.class);
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "a.db", null, 1);
    }
}
```